# (PYTHON) Why calling a function that returns a print function does print?

Tags: python, function, printing, return

So here is the idea :

```
def printing():
    print("Hello World! WOW SO ORIGINAL!!!!")

def returning():
    return printing()

returning()
```

and if the code is run it prints :

```
Hello World! WOW SO ORIGINAL!!!!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The same goes if use arguments in the function.

Why? How about other languages ?

Comment: Why would you expect it not to print?

Comment: Instead of returning `printing`, you are actually calling the function `printing` and not returning a reference to it.

Comment: If wouldn't expect to not print either, I just didn't know what it would do

Comment: Well, you ran the code and saw what it does. What exactly is your question?

Comment: No I called the returning() function

Comment: Why does it work like this ? I mean Python is not magic

Comment: I feel like you aren't distinguishing between the *side effect* of writing to standard output and the *return value* of a function.

Comment: *"I called the returning() function"* – Yes, and the `returning` function called the `printing` function.

Answer (score 1):

Once you call the function `printing`, first it executes the `print("Hello World! WOW SO ORIGINAL!!!!")` and then it returns `None` as any function without return statement in python. Thus, `returning` also returns the `None` value returned by `printing`.

Answer (score 0):

```
return printing()
```

is equvialent to

```
temp = printing()
return temp
```

In both cases, the `printing` function is called, which causes it to print its message.

You might be thinking of

```
return printing
```

This just returns a reference to the function without calling it, so it never executes.